# How to convert the Absolute Uri path from .net to .net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am converting my asp.net project to asp.net core. 
It throws a few errors that i need your assistance to fix. enter image description here

enter code here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl()
```